# How to configure class definition to consume Unicode marked JSON

Tags: vb.net, json.net

If I use the regex function to remove the `u'`, the JSON is consumed correctly. Is there a way in Newtonsoft to process it without the regex preprocessing?

I am using VB.net if it makes a difference.
Here is a snippet for some context:

```
{
  "memo": [
    "{u'braums': {u'printing_data': {u'customerFirstName': u'xxxxxx', u'orderNumber': 4495, u'customerLastName': u'xxxxxx', u'num_refrigerated_labels': 1, u'num_dry_labels': 1, u'packedBy': u'xxxxxxx xxxxxxx', u'pickupTime': u'11/18/2020 15:00', u'num_frozen_labels': 0}}}",
    "{u'braums': {u'cancellation_reasons': {u'who': u'xxxxxxx', u'when': u'11/18/2020 8:02 PM', u'why': u'called to cancel'}}}"
  ]
}
```

As per @dbc suggestion, here is an example that shows the issue.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/pM1qs2

I expanded his `TestClass` with a sub that removes the Unicode markers using regex (`TestClass.ShowMemoWork()`) and then a sub that leaves the Unicode markers (`TestClass.ShowMemoIssue()`)

The fact that `JObject` worked, means there is something in the syntax that I am missing.

Comment: Your JSON is malformed - it's missing outer braces.  If I add those Json.NET can deserialize your JSON successfully, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/0J3RcH.  What exactly is your problem?  Is it that you are trying to bind the JSON to a model with property names that don't have the `u'`?  Or is it that you are parsing to a `JObject` and you want the u'`? stripped?  Or are you getting an exception somewhere?  If you can please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] it's more likely we can help.

Comment: @dbc The reason it was posted malformed, the memo is just one key of a bigger class. I was just posting it for context, but I see the confusion. I love getting feedback to be able to ask clearer questions.
I may have been using the deserialized term wrong. We deserialized using a class, so I may be making too big of a jump. 
BTW, this answer may answer another question I have on how to deserialize the memo. Right now I have to go to a string before deserializing it. I would like to go straight to NDOrder_memo, but that will be a different thread. This example will work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Json.Net does not support having a `u` prefix in front of strings in JSON. This is definitely not part of the JSON standard, as you can see [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). `\u` can be used *inside* a string to prefix a string of 4 hex digits to represent a unicode character, but that is entirely different than what is in your sample.

I think you are being tricked into thinking it "works" with `JObject`, but you aren't really doing the same test in that case.  In your `ShowMemoIssue` example, you first deserialize the full JSON (which works fine), and then you attempt to deserialize one of the strings from the `memo` array.  The second step fails because that string isn't valid JSON due to the `u` prefixes.

But you never try the second step with the `JObject`.  You only deserialize the outer JSON and then print it out, calling it a success.  If you try to take one of the array items and deserialize that to a `JObject`, you will see that it fails in the same way.  Here is a demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7XQpd

So in short, I think you will have to continue to use the regex preprocessing to handle your JSON.  Better yet would be to change the emitter of the JSON not to include the invalid prefixes in the first place, but I understand that may not be in your control.

Comment: Unforntualy changing the emitter is not an option at this point. Hopefully, the regex solution will not cause issues down the road. I wonder why a language such as python would do something that is not standard? I was afraid that I was going to get your answer, now I can allow my OCD to move on. :-) Thanks for your and dbc time.

Comment: Glad I could help, but sorry this is not the answer you were hoping for.  I'm no Python expert, but if I had to guess, the emitter is probably using `str()` instead of `json.dumps()` to create the output.  In Python 2.x, `str()` will create a JSON-like string representation of an object where unicode strings are prefixed with `u`.  But it's not actually JSON.  `json.dumps()` will create correct JSON without the `u` prefixes.